# How are bytes represented in a file by Ocaml?

Tags: hex, ocaml, bytecode

I'm trying to write a function to write a list of bytes to a file (we're writing a parser of the .class file and after some insertions writing the file back.) When my partner wrote the code to read it in, the bytecode list variable is a list of ints. So now I need to convert it to bytes and then write it to a new .class file. Will the representation of the hex numbers be the same essentially so that the new .class file can be processed by the JVM? My functional programming is LISP from a single semester three years ago and a semester of Coq one year ago. Not enough to make me think in functional terms easily.

Comment: I don't see what this has to do with functional programming. I don't understand the question either: What your program does with the bytes depends on how you wrote the code.

Comment: I see how my introducing myself as new to functional programming was confusing, the question has nothing to do with functions but with how OCaml represents bytes in a file. The bytes from a class file were read in using open_in_bin into a stream that was converted for some reason to an int list. I was given this and told to parse the class file and write it to a byte file and I wondered if converting the int list to a byte sequence would be something that the JVM could still read. I was hoping that someone had experience with this odd mix of OCaml and Java. That's all.

Comment: Do the integers represent byte values, or components in the [JVM .class file format](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se7/html/jvms-4.html)? (I.e., the different `u2`s and `u4`s of the format specification.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your question is, in fact, pretty confusing. Here's some code that reads in the bytes of a file as an int list, then writes the ints back out as bytes to a new file. On a reasonable system (you don't mention your system), this will copy a file exactly so that no program including the JVM can tell the difference.

```
let get_bytes fn =
    let inc = open_in_bin fn in
    let rec go sofar =
        match input_char inc with
        | b -> go (Char.code b :: sofar)
        | exception End_of_file -> List.rev sofar
    in
    let res = go [] in
    close_in inc;
    res

let put_bytes fn ints =
    let outc = open_out_bin fn in
    List.iter (fun b -> output_char outc (Char.chr b)) ints;
    close_out outc

let copy_file infn outfn =
    put_bytes outfn (get_bytes infn)
```

I tested this on my system (OS X 10.11.2). I don't have any class files around, but the JVM had no trouble running a jarfile copied with `copy_file`.

The essence of this problem has nothing to do with hexadecimal numbers. Those are a way of representing numbers as strings, which don't appear anywhere. It also has little to do with functional programming, other than the fact that you want to write your code in OCaml.

The essence of the problem is the meaning of a series of bytes stored in a file. At the lowest level, the bytes stored in the file *are* the meaning of the file. So you can faithfully copy the file just by copying the bytes. That's what `copy_file` does.

Since you want to *change* the bytes, you of course need to make sure your new bytes represent a valid class file. Once you've figured out the new bytes that you want, you can write them out with `put_bytes` (on a reasonable system).